# How to prevent git commit tool from closing after a commit?

Tags: git, user-interface, configuration

The git GUI commit tool closes after clicking "commit" - is there any way to keep it open? Sometimes I want to commit multiple times, and having to reopen the commit tool adds an extra unnecessary step. (I'm using msysgit on Windows XP, if it matters.)

Comment: Are you sure yuo ran 'git gui' and not 'git citool' ? 'git citool' closes after a single commit. 'git gui' keeps running.

Comment: I didn't know there was a difference. I'm on Windows, so I ran "Git Commit Tool" from the Explorer menu, so I guess I am running citool. Problem solved. Go ahead and answer the question below so I can give you some karma.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you run `git gui` and not `git citool`. `git citool` closes after a single commit. `git gui` keeps running and lets you do more than one commit.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I have an alias set up to repeatedly invoke `git citool` as long as there are still changes and the window wasn't closed without making a commit.

```
[alias]
ci = "!while ! git diff --quiet && git citool; do true; done"
```

The benefit of using this approach over `git gui` is that you automatically come back to the prompt after everything is committed.